# Jquery Toggle in Wordpress

Tags: jquery, wordpress, toggle

I'am working on a Team member page in Wordpress. 
This team member page should be automatically filled when new members are added. 
I used the plugin CPT UI and this works great.

The content is hidden so that only images are beeing seen on the team page. 
Works fine.

But now i want to toggle the hidden content when clicked on the image.

What i have till this far works great for the first image, but when second image is clicked, the content of the first "image" toggles

so i think i need some kind of loop for this?

i'am a complete beginner with Jquery / javascript so i hope some one can help me out.

```
 get_header(); ?>


<div id="page-content-wrapper">
     <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-12">
            <a href="#menu-toggle" class="btn btn-default" id="menu-toggle"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-hamburger"> </span></a>

    <section id="team-images">                      



<?php $loop = new WP_Query( array ('post_type' => 'team' , 'orderby' => 'post_id' , 'order' => 'ASC') ); ?>

<?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?> 


<div id="test-bob"> 

<?php 
    if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
        the_post_thumbnail( array( 200 , 200 ) );
}
?>

<section id="team-data"> 
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12"> 
<?php the_title(); ?> 
<?php the_content(); ?>



</div>
</div>

</div> 


</section>

</div>

<?php endwhile; ?>   


 <script>
    $("#test-bob").click(function() {

    $("#team-data").toggle("slow" , function() {

        // animation complete.
    });

});



</script>  
    </section>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What i have till this far works great for the first image, but when second image is clicked, the content of the first "image" toggles --- ***this happen because the ID only take the first element.***

Look like the element `<div id="test-bob">` and `<section id="team-data">` was inside while loop. And you call them in jquery by ID. The ID should be unique, change the Id into class definition like so(*I'm assuming the js code already works and just need modified*. ) :

```
//I'm just taking the needed part
<div class="test-bob"> //<--- this
<?php 
  if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
    the_post_thumbnail( array( 200 , 200 ) );
  }
?>

  <section class="team-data"> //<-- this
    <div class="container-fluid">
     <div class="row">
       <div class="col-sm-12"> 
       <?php the_title(); ?> 
       <?php the_content(); ?>
```

**JS should be :**

```
 <script>
 // should wrapped inside document ready
 $(function(){ 
    $(document).on('click','.test-bob',function() {
      $(this).find(".team-data").toggle("slow" , function() {
         // animation complete.
      });
    });
 });
</script>
```

Hope this work for you. If not, reply in comment.

Comment: Thank you very much! this was exactly what i'am looking for!